# Moving data from datetime column to date column

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, types

In MySQL, I have a column with the `datetime` data type and I would like to transfer the data into a column with the `date` datatype. My goal is to have a new column that only containes the date without the time. I have already created a new column with the `date` data type but I don't know how to most efficiently transfer the data from one column to the other. Also, would I run into compatibility issues trying to transfer `datetime` data into a `date` column?

Comment: Why !!! Just use the Date part of DateTime if that what you want. `DATE(yourdatetime)` then you can also still get to a time if you want `TIME(yourdatetime)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly sometimes on large queries when joining date columns to datetime columns (also with using DATE() you lose indexing and speed. Then it is easier to just create a date column. So depends on the situation. On some of our databases we split date and time in different columns to keep the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, everyone. I think both approaches serve a purpose. We have the liberty and resources to create another column so I went with that approach this time around just in case it is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql auto converts to the date format if you transfer the date but you could use DATE(datetime) as format

```
UPDATE table SET dateColumn = DATE(dateTimeColumn);
```

So dateColumn is the new column here and this is not going to give compatibility issues.